# CSS positioning: all variants tried, no progress

Tags: css, positioning

I ve read the other postings regarding somewhat similar issues. But this "somewhat" doesnt help.

Case:

In a table cell, I have a thumb pic. It docks itself to the top left corner without my indicating anything. Fine.
Then I want words referring to that pic. If I do nothing, they align themselves UNDERNEATH of the pic and paralell to the left side of the cell.

Theory:

I want the words aligned not underneath but to the right of the pic. No way to get that.

1. Forget about absoulute positioning because we are displaying dynamically an unknown number of rows so it would be a mess in relation to the coordinates of the page.
2. If you try to position them using the margin-left, margin-right etc, it will not work either. Reason: each town has a different length, so what is fine for one word is not fine for other word.
3. If you try relative positioning it will not work either. Reason: The rules say that relative stuff positions the dependants in relation to THE NORMAL POSITION OF THE ELEMENT. We have seen that the normal position of the element was to alight underneath the picture, so while I can position them in relation to that very first one, it turns out that the first one is positioned wrongly, therefore, all of the dependants would be too.

If I position the first element in the place I WANT by using the marging-right etc the relative positioning of the other elements will not work, because the position I WANT is not the one that the word would position itself in the document.

I have this elements:
pic
price
town
region
being the elements, other than the pic

```
<tr class=<?php  echo $fila?>>


<td>
<?php echo "<img src= http://localhost/housing2/assets/uploads/thumbs/$oferta->thumb_a>"?>

<ul>

<li>
<div id ="listado"><?php echo $oferta->price?></div>
</li>

<li class = "listado.town">
<div id ="listado_town" ><?php echo $oferta->nombre_localidad?></div>
</li>

<li class = "listado.region">
<div id ="listado_region"><?php echo $oferta->nombre_region?></div>
</li>

<li class = "listado.m2">
<div id ="listado_metros" ><?php echo $oferta->m2?></div>
</li>

</ul>


</td>
```

and the css

```
.listado.town{position:relative; bottom:10px;}
.listado.region{position:relative;bottom:15px;}
.listado.m2{position:relative;bottom:20px;}
```

but this is just one of the 20 occurrences I have tried.  This one aligns all elements underneath the picture and to the left side, actually I believe it is so incorrec that the reader ignores my mistakes and then it just aligns them as they would naturally go in the document

OTHER COMBINATIONS:

Considering that the guiding tag is the Price, I let that position itself where it would naturally go in the document, and as I said, it locates itself underneath the pic.
Then I am able to position all of the rest correctly by using the position relative, yes that is easy and as expected, but the parent one, the price, is incorrectly positioned:

This would be so

```
li.listado_town{position:relative; bottom:160px; left:130px;}
li.listado_region{position:relative;bottom:150px; left:130px;}
li.listado_m2{position:relative;bottom:140px; left:130px;}
```

Comment: And why aren't you *showing us* your (relevant) HTML and CSS? Why are you describing it at us..?

Comment: because I have tried all insane combinations and they are all nonsense, so if i dont have the concept clear, it is useless: I am gong to post them then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by telling the image to `float: left;` **and** making sure your table cell is wide enough

```
td {
    min-width: 400px;
}
img {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

- check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/zjA4f/

Alternatively, if you don't want to specify the table widths, you could make the `ul` element inline. Added benefit of easily being able to position it with respect to the image using `vertical-align`:

```
img {
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

​

(See http://jsfiddle.net/zjA4f/2/)

Comment: I am going to try that. Gracias

Comment: Gracias Manuel. It worked right out of the box. So, I did not need to use any class, while I have spent one day and a half in countless combinations. There is one problem: in my display, the elements li are too far from each other, I want them a little closer, but it seems the li just makes them that way.

Comment: Other idea, based on what you proposed, is to simply let the picture be the element from which all other elements are RELATIVE to. I was doing that with price, but price located itself wrongly, therefore, if the picture locates itself correctly, then I can css relative positiom them all, not just as LI but any way.

Comment: Removing the LI solves the problem of the distance. One question, what if I want to position them like: Price and to the right Localidad and then underneath the rest of the elements. In this case, I do need to use the classes and the CSS relative positioning, don't I?

Comment: `li` and `ul` elements come with some built-in styling. You can play round with `margin: 0px` in the `li` elements or `list-style: none` in the `ul` to modify that. If you want both price and location in one line, just have them in the same `li` element!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give width to the  around the picture. And next you should add another  for the words.

Something like:

```
<div>
     <div width="10px" style="float: left; margin-right:10px;">picture</div>
     <div width="10px" style="float: left;">
          <p>word</p>
          <p>word1</p>
          <p>.....</p>
          <p>word20</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Paste the code [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-align) (delete the old code first) and see the result.

Comment: In the example you give me, the problem is that the first heading positions itself where it wants, and in my case it was not where I wanted. Therefore, all the relative elements would be correctly located but with regards to an incorrectly located element. The problem is to position the first one right.